# Why use ASP.NET membership provider when you can just use Repositories? Is it better security?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, repository, membership-provider

I just finished implementing a custom membership provider and after the whole thing was done I'm just wondering why is it nessesary?

In my project I'm using Open ID to authenticate and once I have the users Open ID I forward them right off the bat to get OAuth request/access token then log them in using forms authentication. I'm only ever using the CreateUser() and GetUser() from the membership provider.

Can I just use my own Repository to store all of the data I need (AccessToken, Username, OpenId, etc) or is there something I'm not seeing behind the scenes that I should be aware about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly use your own repository to store all the data you need. (In fact, you would use your own repository to store the information used by ASP.NET Membership.)

It's simply a matter of if you are willing and able to write your own code. Given that there are some security concerns, you should probably review your own design, if implemented, for security issues.

Comment: Yes I am using my own repositoreis to get/set the data I need from the database and it was a pain in the ass because I had to inject the repo into the membership provider which wasn't trivial... Thanks that's all the confirmation I needed :)

EDIT: Actually without using the membership provider can I still use the role provider and/or is it better to implement my own solution?

Comment: AFAIC, you can use any part of it as long as you have sufficient understanding of what you need. The ASP.NET Membership is nothing more than a collection of routines and a database schema. I personally use ASP.NET Membership and simply add the classes I need. It's really just a matter of choice and of what your particular needs are.